# Bizarre exception code in C++, exit value 1,073,740,940 (code: 0xc0000374), when user input is 23

Tags: c++, runtime-error

When the user input is exactly 23, I get this error thrown. It's some kind of [heap corruption](http://errorco.de/win32/ntstatus-h/status_heap_corruption/0xc0000374/), but I have no idea how to fix it. It's just a simple homework assignment whereby it creates a dynamically allocated character array, the length of which is determined by the user. It then displays the array, sorts in alphabetical order, and then displays it.

Program:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cctype>
#include<string>
#include<ctime>

using namespace std;

void showArray(char *array)
{
    for (int count = 0; *(array + count) != '\0'; count++)
        cout << *(array + count) << " ";
    cout << endl;
}

void selectionSort(char *array)
{
    {
       int startScan, minIndex, minValue;

       for (startScan = 0; *(array + startScan) != '\0'; startScan++)
       {
          minIndex = startScan;
          minValue = *(array + startScan);
          for(int index = startScan + 1; *(array + index) != '\0'; index++)
          {
             if (*(array + index) < minValue)
             {
                minValue = *(array + index);
                minIndex = index;
             }
          }
          *(array + minIndex) = *(array + startScan);
          *(array + startScan) = minValue;
       }
    }
}

int main()
{
    int N,
        count;
    string str;
    unsigned int i;
    char min = 97,
         max = 122,
         quit,
         ch;
    srand(time(0));

    while(true)
    {
        char *arrayPtr = nullptr;
        while(true)
        {
            cout << "How many N's do you want?" << endl;
            cin >> str;
            bool truTru = true;

            for (i = 0; i < str.length(); i++)
            {
                char c = str.at(i);
                if ((int)c < 48 || (int)c > 57)
                {
                    cout << "Make sure you are entering numbers, ya dummie." << endl;
                    truTru = false;
                    break;
                }
                /*else if (str == "23")
                {
                    cout << "Sorry, 23 is an invalid input for some reason." << endl;
                    cout << "I need you to enter something diffrent" << endl;
                    truTru = false;
                    break;
                }*/
            }

            if (!truTru)
                continue;
            else
                break;
        }

        N = atoi(str.c_str());
        arrayPtr = new char[N + 1];
        arrayPtr[N + 1] = '\0';

    for(count = 0; count < N; count++)
            arrayPtr[count] = min + (rand() % (max - min));

        showArray(arrayPtr);

        selectionSort(arrayPtr);

        showArray(arrayPtr);

        delete[] arrayPtr;

        cout << "Wanna enter more N's? (1 = no, 2 = yes)" << endl;
        cin >> quit;
            while(true)
            {
                if (quit == '1' || quit == '2')
                        break;
                else
                    {
                        cout << "Incorrect input." << endl;
                        cout << "Try again." << endl;
                        cin >> quit;
                        continue;
                    }
            }
            if (quit == '1')
                break;
            else
            {
                cin.ignore();
                cout << "\nPress ENTER to continue." << endl;
                ch = cin.get();
            }
    }
cout << "Thanks for your N's!" << endl;

return 0;
}
```

You can see that my solution has been commented out. If I check for the number 23, the program works perfectly. I'm also using Eclipse IDE on a Razer Blade R2 with an i7-3632QM, 8gb RAM, 64bit Windows 8.1, if that makes a difference.

**EDIT:** I should mention that the purpose of the assignment was to use array pointers. So, using the size of the array to determine when the for loops ends was out of the question. That's why I needed the `[N+1] = '\0'` in order to determine when the for loops were supposed to finish.

Comment: `arrayPtr[N + 1] = '\0';` => `arrayPtr[N] = '\0';`

Comment: Don't use magic numbers.  If you want to express a character use a character literal like `'A'` instead of `65`.

Comment: `if ((int)c < 48 || (int)c > 57)` -- Please do this instead: `if (!isdigit(c))` -- Your code is not only harder to read without using literals, it relies on ASCII being the encoding used.  There is a reason for `isdigit` -- the compiler will do the right thing, depending on the encoding used.

Comment: Minor point: `*(array + count)` is usually written as `array[count]`.

Comment: *It has already been submitted and I got an A,* -- That just shows the sad state that the teaching of C++ finds itself.  The program was wrong to begin with, and if you were to use `std::vector` instead of `new[]/delete[]`, you would have had a better chance to discover this error yourself (using `vector::at()`, for example).

Comment: Lots of code. Narrow it down to a [MCVE]

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie: That really is shocking :(

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Haha, ouch. This is only my second comp sci class. I just learned isdigit like a week ago.

Comment: @PeteBecker The point of the assignment is that I wasn't allowed to use the [] at all in the display and sorting functions. I was learning about how to use pointers.

Comment: "It has already been submitted and I got an A" - So? That means *nothing* except that those grading you don't know how to write proper, bug free, modern, C++. Don't believe that everything that is taught/graded in school is gold - it is usually *far* from that.

Comment: @trialAndError just for laughs: `for (int count = 0; *(array + count) != '\0'; count++)` becomes `for(;*array;++array)`

Comment: @JesperJuhl Well, I mean ya, that's why I'm here. I wasn't trying to brag or anything. My professor's grading rhubric seems crazy subjective to me anyway. I at an A for this program that has a runtime error, and prgram that works perfectly, but just looks ugly. And an A for a program that looks an acts perfectly, but I didn't include one small parameter that was required that I missed. So...what are you gonna do?

Comment: @trialAndError well, if you ask *me* (which may or may not be advisable); then I would say that programming should be learned from a) personal study/practice. b) knowledgeable/expert coworkers. c) good books.      School? Naah, not so much. ;)

Comment: @JesperJuhl Fair, but I needs me that degree, bruh

Comment: @trialAndError well, I'm 41 years old. Started programming on the amiga when I was about ~14 or so. Never finished highschool (or any other "official" school). Currently hold a job writing software analyzing and managing radiology images that's used across a number of hospitals. All I needed was an interest in programming and the field I was working in and a will to study on my own. School/degree not needed. What's needed is knowing what you are doing. A degree is just a piece of paper.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The below is a problem:

```
 arrayPtr = new char[N + 1];
 arrayPtr[N + 1] = '\0';
```

if you allocate N+1 the index goes from 0 to N, accessing N+1 is heap corruption

Comment: But why does it happen only when I enter 23? I did N+1 because I need the last one to be the null terminator so my sorting and displaying functions knew where to stop. I'm not allowed to use the actual size (N) of the array to determine the length of it.

Comment: Going beyond the bounds of your array is undefined behavior.  Anything can happen.

Comment: @trialAndError and you are doing that part correctly in `for(count = 0; count < N; count++)` i.e. you never use `count == N`. that's where the nul char should be, not in N+1. 23 is just a random number related to your current state of the machine it can change randomly.

Comment: @trialAndError let's say N is 2. you allocated 2+1=3 items: `arrayPtr[0]`, `arrayPtr[1]` and `arrayPtr[2]`. as you can see if you try to get to `arrayPtr[N+1]` i.e. `arrayPtr[3]` you are going out of bounds

Comment: @IlBeldus But it seems to me that    arrayPtr[N+1] is still    arrayPtr[2]

Comment: @IlBeldus Nope, nope, I get it now. Thanks.